# Create JavaScript Date object from m/d/Y H:I:s

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a JavaScript Date object from a from m/d/Y H:I:s string.  Below is my attempt.  It works fine without the `H:I:s`, but does not work with it.  How do I create JavaScript Date object from m/d/Y H:I:s?

```
var dt='  5/5/1964   11:13:00 ';
var valid=false;
dt = dt.replace('  ',' ');    //Get rid of double spaces
dt.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''); //Trim string
dt=dt.split(' ');
var d=(dt[0])?dt[0].split('/'):[];
var t=(dt[1])?dt[1].split(':'):[];
if (d.length === 3) {
    d=[d[2],d[1]-1,d[0]];   //Change to YMD and month to 0 to 11
    //var date=new Date.apply(null, d.concat(t));  //doesn't work
    dt = d.concat(t).join();
    console.log(dt);
    var date=new Date(dt);
    console.log(date);
    if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === "[object Date]" && !isNaN( date.getTime() )) {
        // it is a date and is valid.  date.valueOf() could also work instead of date.getTime()
        valid=true;
    }
}
if(valid){ doSomethingWithDate(date);}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real need in special parsing of the string, as the `Date` class constructor (internally [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)) can parse the given format automatically:

```
var date = new Date('  5/5/1964   11:13:00 ');
console.log(date);  // e.g. Tue May 05 1964 11:13:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

See more examples of the formats in [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Examples).

Comment: Thanks VisioN.  Works with all common browser?

Comment: @user1032531 Should do, according to the standards.

Answer (score 1):

Running `new Date(" 5/5/1964 11:13:00 ")` worked just fine for me.